# Interactive SVG does note work in my Joomla site

Tags: svg, joomla, interactive

I am using an interactive svg in Joomla. For some reason, when I click on the clickable area, it does not respond in Joomla, but when I load the image standalone in the browser it works. Can anyone help?

Here's the details: 
- I have added svg as an accepted image file extension in Joomla and the svg image can be uploaded and used in an article, so the basic config works. I have used multiple svg images on the same website without problem. The difference is that this svg is has links in the image.

Here is the content of the svg:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Laag_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 283.5 283.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 283.5 283.5;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#F39200;}
</style>
<a xlink:href="https://www.google.com">
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M217.2,66.1c41.9,41.9,41.9,109.9,0,151.8s-109.9,41.9-151.8,0S23.5,108,65.4,66.1
            C107.4,24.2,175.3,24.2,217.2,66.1"/>
    </g>
</g>
</a>
</svg>
```

It is just a simple example of a circle that is clickable and links to Google. If you click outside of the circle, nothing happens.

Here you can see this image in a page: https://www.thomsterdam.nl/?view=article&id=34&catid=11 
As you can see the image is there, but when you click on the circle nothing happens.

This the URL of the image: https://www.thomsterdam.nl/images/leger.svg 
When you click on the image, you are taken to google, as expected (see code above).

Of course this is just a simple example. I have more complicated svg images that I want to use on a production site.

If anyone knows the solution, I would be much obliged. I have used a clickable svg image in the past, so it should be possible to use, but..... no such luck here.

BTW:

1. if you move the `a xlink:href.....` to be wrapped around the `path`, instead of the `g`, it makes no difference.
2. if you replace *xlink:href* with *href* it doesn't make any difference either. It still won't work.

Thanx in advance.

Thom

Comment: This is because you are using it as an image. Try using it as an inline svg

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can you tell me more?

Comment: Please read this article: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image